# Problemas de Conexión con SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

espero todos estén al menos con salud. Estoy desarrollando un sistema bastante largo y complejo y con cierta regularidad recibo un error de SQL Server:

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Se agotó el tiempo de espera de ejecución. El período de tiempo de espera transcurrió antes de la finalización de la operación o el servidor no responde.'**

Esto es algo que no entiendo, ya que no sucede siempre y como no domino bien el seteo de SQL Server no se si es que hay que configurar algo en el mismo.

Cualquier ayuda, observación o idea será bien recibida y agradecida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto `SqlCommand` tiene por defecto un tiempo de espera (tiempo máximo de ejecución) de 30 segundos.

Si la operación a realizar supera ese tiempo es necesario considerar lo siguiente:

- Un mal diseño de la base de datos
- Unos índices inexistentes o mal diseñados
- Un dimensionado del hardware erróneo.
- Un hecho puntual que hay que tratar como una excepción.

Si se trata del último punto siempre podemos aumentar el tiempo de espera de la ejecución del objeto `SqlCommand`. Ejemplo:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select campo from tabla where nombre = 'UnNombre'");
//Aumentamos a 2 minutos el tiempo de espera de la ejecución
comm.CommandTimeout = 120;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Para poder ayudarte de forma más precisa sería necesario conocer más sobre tu aplicación, por ejemplo el código que genera el error o las operaciones que estás realizando sobre la base de datos.

La razón por la que tienes este error puede ser que tu servidor de base de datos no responda durante un determinado periodo de tiempo, por ejemplo porque pierde conexión con la red o porque tenga demasiada carga de trabajo.

Otra razón puede ser que estés realizando una operación demasiado costosa, por ejemplo una consulta que devuelva muchas filas. Si este es tu caso puedes probar a incluir algún índice en la tabla que estás consultando.